# Angular2 EXCEPTION No provider for String

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I've got a brand new app create with a ng-cli
with this very simple code ^^

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private my: string) {}
}
```

and I've got in the console

**EXCEPTION: No provider for String!**

I don't see any error in the code so
what's wrong !

In ng-book I can read

```
export class Article { 
  title: string; 
  link: string; 
  votes: number;
  constructor(title: string, link: string, votes?: number) { 
    this.title = title;
    this.link = link;
    this.votes = votes || 0;
  }
}
```

### Take a look at

https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScriptSamples/blob/master/greeter/greeter.ts

Comment: The DI system is trying to inject a value for you; what were you expecting `my` to be? Where should the value come from?

Comment: a string a ts type in plain ts is a valid sintax

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to say.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScriptSamples/blob/master/greeter/greeter.ts

Comment: But you're using Angular 2, where the constructor parameters for components are injected by DI. This *isn't* just plain TS.

Comment: You can do in a class (ie a service) but NOT in a component :) see the reply above

Comment: A class isn't necessarily a service. Services are `@Injectable`, and *also* use DI for constructor parameters. See e.g. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt4.html - you need to review the basics

Comment: I wrote ie a service

Comment: But services are more like components than other classes, making that an actively counterproductive example.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Error in constructor:

```
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private my: string) {}
}
```

`private my: string` should not be injected in the constructor, but outside, here assuming it's a variable you want to use in your component.

```
export class AppComponent {
  private my: string;
  constructor() {
    this.my = 'Hello!'; // if you want to assign a value (in the constructor) to your string, do it here!
  }
}
```

I suggest you start of with the [**Tutorial**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/) from the beginning, so you learn the basics of Angular :)

EDIT, the latter part you added is a class e.g for typing your object, not a component, for a typed Object of class Article, this is valid syntax:

```
export class Article { 
  title: string; 
  link: string; 
  votes: number;
  constructor(title: string, link: string, votes?: number) { 
    this.title = title;
    this.link = link;
    this.votes = votes || 0;
  }
}
```

Then you can import this class to your `AppComponent`, and use to assign an `Article` object.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Article } from './your.path'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  article: Article = new Article('titleHere', 'linkHere', 3)

  constructor() {}
}
```

Comment: It's a ts valid sintax its not about angular itself

Comment: But all in all  AppComponent is a class - What's the different from component and a class ? imo the angular di should be aware that the param is a string

Comment: @Whisher it is aware that it's a string. It doesn't know **which string that should be**. Hence the error.

Comment: a string as a type is a string so I wait the same plain ts behaviour

Comment: @Whisher To cut things short and MUCH simplified, the `@Component` decorator tells that AppComponent is a not a "normal" class, but a Component. And in that case you would have to tell that `string` is a provider for your component, because it expects that what is in injected in the constructor should be a provider, and therefore declared in `providers: [string]` in your component or ngModule. "string" wouldn't work as it's no known angular 2 provider, unless you create a service (or whatever) that is named `string` and has Angular magic in it ;) As said this was just a simplified example.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error and can solve it

just need to re-run the build process

by stopping it with cntrl+c

and `ionic serve` again

or angular command