# Angular2: inline template:8:0 caused by: No provider for String

Tags: angular

I wrote the following code in Angular2:

**add-item.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'add-item',
  template: `<form-item [title]="abcde"></form-item>`,
})

export class AddItemComponent {
  forms: Object[]

  constructor() {
    this.forms = [{title: 'a', link: 'b'}];
  }
}
```

**form-item.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'form-item',
  template: `<h3>{{title}}</h3>`,
  inputs: ['title'],
  styles: [`
    h3 { 
        color: blue;      
    }
  `]
})

export class FormItemComponent{

  @Input()
  title: string;

  constructor(title: string) {
    this.title = title;
  }
}
```

When I run this code I get an error:

> Error: Error in ./AddItemComponent class AddItemComponent - inline
>   template:8:0 caused by: No provider for String!

I did a small research and I don't understand what is the problem. I also looked here:
[Angular2 EXCEPTION No provider for String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41882599/angular2-exception-no-provider-for-string)

Can you please help me?

Comment: Have a look at this article on MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt795191

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `title: string` and initialization from a constructor. Angular's constructor expecting providers as arguments.

Answer (score 1):

FormItemComponent class should be:

```
export class FormItemComponent{
  @Input() title: string = "";
}
```

'title' must not be initialized inside a constructor.