# NullInjectorError: No provider for String

Tags: angular, typescript

After adding a string parameter to the constructor in my class I am getting an error in the browser:

[image]

My class is defined as follow:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { MatrixComponent } from '../matrix/matrix.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-player',
  templateUrl: './player.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./player.component.css']
})
export class PlayerComponent implements OnInit {
    private userName: string;

    constructor(private name: string) {
        this.userName = name;
        this.discovered = 0;
        this.matrix = new MatrixComponent();
    }

    ngOnInit() {
    }
}
```

And I am creating the object in the constructor of another class:

```
var player1 = new PlayerComponent("Me");
```

I think it is possible to pass parameters in the constructor right? What's wrong with my code?

Comment: *creating the object in the constructor of another class* - and you shouldn't. It's a component, not some generic class. It's instantiated by Angular compiler. It's unclear what you're trying to achieve, but it isn't supposed to work like that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41882599/2332159) question,

the `@Component` decorator tells `angular` that it is a not a normal `typescript class`, but an `Angular Component`.

Thus, to make it work, you would have to tell it that `string` is a `provider` for your component, as it expects the constructor parameter to be a provider (which is either declared in the component's `metadata` or in the module).

`string` wouldn't work as it's not a known angular 2 provider (unless you create a service with name `string`).

This explains why we can create these kind of constructors (`string` as arguments) in normal classes but are not allowed in angular components.

I hope this helps :)